# Group by while using union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to union all two queries, which one having a group by and another is just a hard-coded value without a table.

```
SELECT 'All' Category 
UNION
SELECT Category as Category
FROM WV_BlogData
GROUP BY Category
ORDER BY COUNT(BlogDataID) desc
```

I am getting following error, how to get rid of this?

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 50 Invalid column name 'BlogDataID'.
>   Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 50 ORDER BY items must appear in the
>   select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT
>   operator.

Comment: if i m not wrong order by column should be part of select column list

Comment: At least when UNION (or similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `UNION` up in a derived table:

```
select Category
from
(
    SELECT 'All' Category, 0 as cnt 
    UNION
    SELECT Category as Category, COUNT(BlogDataID) as cnt
    FROM WV_BlogData
    GROUP BY Category
) dt
ORDER BY cnt desc
```